# ffprofile de problema con la última versión de WebDriver y geckodriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Tengo problemas al poner el ffprofile y no sé a que se debe este error ya que ha sido al querer poner la última versión de webdriver y geckodriver.

Esto es lo que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo veo que que el te esta dando problema es FirefoxProfile

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera lo que te falta es que no estas inicializando las opciones de **FirefoxDriver**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(getProfile("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false));
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
}

private static FirefoxProfile getProfile(String profileName) {
if (profileName == null || profileName.trim().isEmpty()) {
    return new FirefoxProfile();
}
return new ProfilesIni().getProfile(profileName);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Raul, cuando llegue a casa lo pruebo y te comento.

Comment: Gracias Raul, Lo estoy probando y creo que en "privatic static FirefoxProfile" falta un parametro para pasarle -> (String profileName, boolean), verdad? ya que como setProfile tenemos ("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false)); [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlFtj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlFtj.png) Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias ya he encontrado la solución,

Dejo la captura de pantalla para el que quiera resolver una duda semejante a la mía.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]